# Warning: Illegal string offset 'category_id' - PHP 5.4 - smarty to php compilation

Tags: php, smarty

I have just moved a site to a new server which is running PHP 5.4.x and can only assume is why im getting this error on a compiled template but as the compiled tpl.php file is generated cannot work out to the point what the issue is and wondering if anyone might know?

The TPL is Smarty and below is the line causing the error:

Original TPL file code: (smarty)

```
{assign var=darin value=$category.category_id}
```

Compiled error file: (compiled from smarty to php cached file)

```
<?php $this->assign('darin', $this->_tpl_vars['category']['category_id'], false); ?>
```

As its compiled an converted i am not sure how to fix on the smarty function so it compiles the correct PHP code thats compiled in cache which is causing the issue... any ideas?

error that is being shown on frontend from compiled file:

```
 Warning: Illegal string offset 'category_id' in /websites/am/domain.com.au/var/cache/templates/customer/%%F3^F39^F3960A5D%%view.override.tpl.php on line 42
```

Thanks in advance,
James

Comment: So you're setting a Smarty variable and want to pull that value back into your PHP controller? Smarty 3 I assume?

Comment: Works fine on 5.3, but 5.4 seems to not. Only noticed as just moved to a new cloud hosting service which is running 5.4 but yea it just grabs the category id such as "10" and assigned to the variable darin. version of smarty im not sure off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

Its mean category isn't an array.

One time print `{{$category}}` var and see type of it.

Comment: It needs to pass the category ID, but done the following:

<p>category: {$category}</p>
<p>category.category_id: {$category.category_id}</p>

and got 
category: Array
category.category_id: 39

Comment: So: "Array" And: "39"

Answer (score 0):

What you should do:

1. Remove cache/compiled files and check if error occurs
2. If error occurs check what contain `$category` variable. Simple it can be not an array or don't have `category_id` index
3. If you don't use the latest Smarty version you should consider upgrading and testing with the newest version (it may be a bug)

If it won't help, please provide `$category` variable data.